# Update empty column in a select query, depending on criteria in same query.

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to fill the column Saneres/Vurderes.

Basically what I need it to do, is that if any of the black marked ones are true in TVObsKode, TVObsKlasse, Type1, Type 2 (ex. "AF>=3 until "RØ">4), it needs to put in a "Saneres" if any of the white ones are true, it should say "Vurderes". I should say, that the column being updated, is created by the query, so it is not an existing table.

[image: Snip from Access]

Any help on doing this, or how I should go about it?

Comment: I can't read that tiny text...

Comment: @jarlh Shift+Click on the image and opens in another window.

Comment: However, not sure what I am seeing. Never seen such complex filter criteria. Does it actually produce desired output? If you want what I think you want, I doubt a simple expression in query will accomplish. Probably need a VBA custom function.

Comment: @June7, sarcasm... (You too?)

Comment: @jarlh Was not intended as sarcasm. Was actually trying to be honest.

Comment: @June7, very nice of you. Have a great day!

Comment: @June7 The criteria are as demanded by the people I work for, so they actually give the desired output :) I'm havign doubt if this at all is possible without VBA, but seeing your comments, it suggest that it isn't.